# WebRTC: ImportError: No module named gyp_chromium

Tags: c++, visual-studio, python-2.7, webrtc

I want to build `WebRTC` on Windows8

I'm following these instructions

http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development

And I'm using this command for building

```
python webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc -G msvs_version=2013
```

When I try to build WebRTC it returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc", line 23,
    import gyp_chromium
ImportError: No module named gyp_chromium
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try ```gclient sync```.

Comment: This question is obsolete now. WebRTC has migrated way from GYP to the new dependency/build system called GN (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools/gn). The webrtc.org instructions are updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the chromium package. When you do a 'fetch webrtc', it is pulled down.  I had the same problem, I just had to follow the instructions (esp. the PreReqs) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps in https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/.

Very important: Make sure as per step 1, On Windows, launch command prompt as Administrator. (right click windows icon, select command `prompt(Admin)`)

I used `cmd` window (without admin mode) and got similar error like `ImportError: No module named gyp_chromium`